# Copying pixeldata between html canvases

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently writing a small image editor to learn some javascript. One of the features is obviously a drawing tool. When that is used i'm drawing those pixels to another canvas on top of the actual canvas and then when the mouse is released i copy over the pixels from the top canvas to the underlying one.

This is the code that is used for the copying of the drawn pixels to the underlying canvas.

```
this.applySketch = function() {
    this.revertStack.push(this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height));

    var real = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    var sketch = this.sketchctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    for(var i = 0; i < sketch.data.length; i += 4) {
        // check the alpha value to decide if to copy to the real canvas
        if(sketch.data[i+3] > 0) {
            real.data[i] = sketch.data[i];
            real.data[i+1] = sketch.data[i+1];
            real.data[i+2] = sketch.data[i+2];
            real.data[i+3] = sketch.data[i+3];
        }
    }

    this.ctx.putImageData(real, 0, 0);
    this.sketchctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
}
```

The problem i'm experiencing is that the pixels don't look the same when they have been copied to the other layer. Instead there is a thin contour of white pixels around whatever it is i'm copying.

Before mouse release (when the pixels are in the top layer)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAK2O.jpg

After mouse release (when they have been copied)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdhSn.jpg

I don't really have any clue on what is going on here because it seems pretty straightforward. Could it be anything with antialiasing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this happens because of antialiasing. When you draw smooth line, some pixels near the line are almost transparent but not fully transparent. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmy7u/) illustrates the problem. So,  you need to merge alpha channel more carefully. The simpliest solution is to add alpha channel value to original value instead of replacing it completely:

```
real.data[i+3] += sketch.data[i+3];
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmy7u/1/) shows the effect. Well, line looks thickly than original line. I suppose you should use some other formula for merging colors.